# Why is Change Type not showing in new alert page?

Tags: alert

I have two web front end servers. When I create new alert for list or library. One server is showing change type in subnew.aspx page (see image). One server not showing this option. Why this server is not showing this option?

But both servers are working in same version.

[image]

Comment: Possibly your installation is corrupt? Can you reproduce this in any other environments?

Comment: Anything you could get from ULS correlation or developer dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

How did you create an alert, click Actions > Alert me or through item Drop down menu >  Alert me? If it is the latter, "Change Type" should not showing. (from a site)